# How to trigger native popup on Leaflet polygon

Tags: leaflet

**How do you manually trigger the native popup on a Leaflet polygon?**

I can bind the native popup to each layer like this:

```
geojsonLayer.on("featureparse", function (e){
    // bind the native popup
    var popupContent = "popup content goes here";
    e.layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
});
```

And I have manually assigned an ID to each polygon so I can reference them later like this:

```
map._layers['poly0']
```

I've tried triggering the popup like this:

```
map._layers['poly0'].openPopup();
```

But that gives me an error like this:

```
map._layers['poly0'].openPopup is not a function
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I provided an answer to my own question here:


    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421127/how-to-trigger-events-on-leaflet-map-polygons

Answer (score 0):

openPopup for vector layers only recently appeared in the latest version, it wasn't there before.

Also, check out the Leaflet 0.4 release announcement: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/2012/07/30/leaflet-0-4-released.html (and note that GeoJSON API was changed and it's not backwards compatible, so you also have to update your code)